# Intuitive explanation of “unit root” sought

Tags: statistics, time-series

I am struggling to get my head around the concept of "unit root" in relation to time series. And it would be a great help if someone could give me a two or three sentence intuitive explanation of the concept.

As an example of the kind of thing I am after, earlier on I also wanted to find the meaning of "hurst exponent"... and it was a great help to find out that it was simply "a measure of the smoothness (as opposed to crinklyness) of the time series" - see image below.

[image]

**EDIT:** Alternatively, a pointer to an online explanation would be good, so long as it includes a good helping of "[Tell them what you are going to tell them](http://www.businesstown.com/presentations/present-tell.asp)".

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). If you do, please link to that question from here before you delete this question...

Comment: Although there already is something similar there: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29121/intuitive-explanation-of-unit-root